# Как найти нужное слово в url и запустить активити?

Tags: android, строки, http, url

Есть url http://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-M6D7JXK

Если его открыть будет много текста. И я хочу сделать поиск в тексте и если найду определенное слово, то производить какие то действия (напр. запружать другое активити).

У меня все вроде работает в логе отображает текст с данного url как System.err, но слово определенное не находит.

```
System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 40884 of // Copyright 2012 Google Inc. All rights reserved.// Container Version: 3(function(w,g){w[g]=w[g]||{};})(window,'google_tag_manager...
```

вот кусок кода который я использую для получения слова

```
String appDomain = "www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=";
                String appName = "GTM-M6D7JXK";

                new HttpTask(new HttpTask.TaskListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFinished(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject appRes = new JSONObject(response);

                            if (appRes.has("self")){
                                Intent Intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainMenu.class);
                                view.getContext().startActivity(Intent);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).execute("http://" + appDomain + appName);
```

И скрипт HTTP

```
public class HttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
public interface TaskListener {
    public void onFinished(String result);
}
private final TaskListener taskListener;
public HttpTask(TaskListener listener) {
    this.taskListener = listener;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
        try {
            if(reader != null)
                reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
    super.onPostExecute(response);
    if(this.taskListener != null) {
        this.taskListener.onFinished(response);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Я вам предлагаю полученный текст разбить на массив

```
str.split(" ");
```

И через цикл поискать нужное слово. Или воспользоваться методом  String

```
str.contains("указываем нужное слово");
```